# Replace value of image src

Tags: jquery

I've these images :

```
<img src="/ar-opt-400x284.png" alt="Projet.">
<img src="/lol-opt-400x284.png" alt="Projet.">
```

I want for these two pictures to remove the string : `-400x284` from `src` attribute

I did this in Jquery but it does not work

```
var src_img = $('img').attr('src');
src.replace('-400x280','');
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The name of your variable is `src_img` but you apply the replace on the variable `src` , that's definitely a problem.

Comment: [Here is a google search result of your question title, verbatim](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Replace+value+of+image+src)